# Pass data to onDestroy() of Service

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I want to know if the service was terminated from a particular activity, so I'm passing a string from that activity while calling `stopServivce(service)`.

Here's the code :

```
Intent service = new Intent(Activity.this,
                        service.class);
                service.putExtra("terminate", "activity terminated service");
                stopService(service);
```

But I can seem to access this variable with `getIntent().getExtras().getString("terminate);` in the `onDestroy()` method.

**[EDIT]**

I found a way around this obstacle, but I'd like my question to still be answered. I just did whatever I had to do in the `onDestroy()` method in the activity and then called `stopService(service)`. I was lucky that my situation didn't need anything more complicated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way of accessing the `Intent` in `onDestroy`.   You have to signal the service some other way (Binder, Shared Preferences, Local Broadcast, global data, or Messenger).  A nice example of using broadcast is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4652540/1904517).  You can also get this to work by calling `startService` instead of `stopService`. `startService` only starts a new services if one does not already exist, so multiple calls to `startService` is mechanism yo send `Intent`s to the service.  You see this trick is use by `BroadcastReceivers`.  Since you have access to the `Intent` in `onStartCommand`, so you can implement termination by check the `Intent` extras and calling `stopSelf` if instructed to terminate.  Here is a sketch of it in action --

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final String terminate = intent.getStringExtra("terminate");

        if(terminate != null) {
            // ... do shutdown stuff
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate what iagreen suggests;

**In Activity**

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
broadcastIntent.setAction("com.package.yourfilter");
broadcastIntent.putExtra("activity_name", "your_activity");

sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

**In Service**

```
 private YourActionReceiver abc;

    this.abc = new YourActionReceiver();

    registerReceiver(this.abc, new IntentFilter("com.package.yourfilter"));

    public class YourActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get the name of activity that sent this message
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Global State

is your friend. :)
Check a Global String whenever you need to (say before terminating). You may also want to have an enumeration `state`. **Or** a flag to see if state is valid.

### Recipe:

The more general problem you are encountering is how to save state across several Activities and all parts of your application. A static variable (for instance, a singleton) is a common Java way of achieving this. I have found however, that a more elegant way in Android is to associate your state with the Application context.

As you know, each Activity is also a Context, which is information about its execution environment in the broadest sense. Your application also has a context, and Android guarantees that it will exist as a single instance across your application.

The way to do this is to create your own subclass of [android.app.Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), and then specify that class in the application tag in your manifest. Now Android will automatically create an instance of that class and make it available for your entire application. You can access it from any context using the Context.getApplicationContext() method (Activity also provides a method getApplication() which has the exact same effect):

```
class MyApp extends Application {

  private String myState;

  public String getState(){
    return myState;
  }
  public void setState(String s){
    myState = s;
  }
}

class Blah extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    ...
    MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
    String state = appState.getState();
    ...
  }
}

class BlahBlah extends Service {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    ...
    MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
    String state = appState.getState();
    ...
  }
}
```

This has essentially the same effect as using a static variable or singleton, but integrates quite well into the existing Android framework. Note that this will not work across processes (should your app be one of the rare ones that has multiple processes).

Credits go to @Soonil