# android - pass a parameter from activity to a service and stop the service

Tags: android, android-service

i have two checked box in my activity. first i want to send some parameter to my service and second if user unchecked the box the service stops. here is my code snipped

here i am passing parameter from my MainActivity but i am not getting it in the service

```
Intent serviceIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("name", "image");
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Service Class

```
public class MyService extends Service {

String selectedAudioPath = "";
private MyThread myythread;
public Intent intent;
public boolean isRunning = false;
long interval=30000;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    myythread  = new MyThread(interval);

}

@Override
public synchronized void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(!isRunning){
        myythread.interrupt();
        myythread.stop();
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    if(!isRunning){
        this.intent = intent;

        myythread.start();
        isRunning = true;
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread{
    long interval;
    public MyThread(long interval){
        this.interval=interval;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(isRunning){
            System.out.println("Service running");
            try {

                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
                if(extras == null)
                    Log.d("Service","null"); // i am getting null here 
                else
                {
                    Log.d("Service","not null");
                    String from = (String) extras.get("name");
                    if(from.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
                        uploadImages();
                    Thread.sleep(interval);
                }else if(from.equalsIgnoreCase("audio")){

                    uploadAudio();
                    Thread.sleep(interval);
                } }



            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                isRunning = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

and second thing i want to stop the service if during process user unchecked the box. i followed this question [How to pass a parameter from an activity to a service...when the user stop the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652011/how-to-pass-a-parameter-from-an-activity-to-a-service-when-the-user-stop-the-s) i followed every step but i got stuck when i write this line

```
registerReceiver(new UserStopServiceReceiver(),  newIntentFilter(USER_STOP_SERVICE_REQUEST));
```

giving me an error on `newIntentFilter` . i thing it has to be declare somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your intent, you didn't specify any bundle, just a string. So, replace this

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

with this

```
String myString = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

For the second question:

```
CheckBox repeatChkBx = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.repeat_checkbox );
repeatChkBx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer. your first solution works for me. ok can you tell me by using your checkbox code the service get stop if it was running ? and second think if it was so easy to stop a service  then why the guy who answered the question in my link which i  posted above has given a so much long explanation

Comment: The link you specify is not related to what you ask. To stop a service you use stopService function.

Comment: i want to stop the service while it is running .. for example i checked the check box now i want to uncheck it so means stop the process. because by using your code my service is not stopping . can you please guide me where  this "newIntentFilter" comes. where should i declare this

Comment: sorry it was a wrong link. sorry for that. can you please look it again

Comment: Use `stopService` EXACTLY the way you use `startService`. e.g. `stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class));`

Comment: i already did it but the service is not stopping when i unchecked it

Comment: I guess you need to check your threading code. From what I can see, your variable `isRunning` is never set to false, to your thread never ends.

Comment: Merlevede so can you please tell me what to do then ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't solve it for you, because I would need to spend a lot of time on this. But I hope I pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: OK, a quick one: set your `isRunning` flag to false in onDestroy(). Also the logic is weird with the (!isRunning)... i think the exclamation mark should go away.

Comment: @Mervelde nope still not stopping